# PHP and WooCommerce Issue

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

If any of you are familiar with WooCommerce you may know that we have a `[add_to_cart id="product_id"]` shortcode to automatically add an item of given `product_id` to the cart.

This works fine while I give the specific ID in the html code, but I want it to be automated, for example getting the ID from a cookie.

The problem with this is that using JavaScript it is not possible to get function because it has to come from the server side but I've been mumbling for hours and getting nowhere with PHP...

What Can I do?

EDIT 1:

what I have is the following:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML= '[add_to_cart id="4158"]';
})
```

and this does not work. Nontheless dinamically with cookies.

Comment: You could try to modify the function, I found it uses wordpress shortcodes and woocomerce register its add_to_cart short code here https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/8ffbd331e0d5694045aec164f027928b43053130/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php#L296 I have no experience with woocomerce so I don't know, but if there is other way to overwrite this functionality than modify it in the original source code, it would be way to go, so any update wont overwrite it or something.

Comment: You can format code by indenting with four spaces or using the `{}` button. The backtick method is best for short snippets of code in a paragraph, not in isolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with an AJAX request to the server sending all the product information I had, it then answered with the

```
do_shortcode()
```

function and I was able to write that answer into some html element to view the button I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give enough information about how you need to retrieve the product ID, but once you have it you could use `do_shortcode()` to automatically insert it into the shortcode:

```
if( isset( $_COOKIE['product_id'] ) ) {
   $product_id = $_COOKIE['product_id']; // Get this from your cookie somehow
   $shortcode = sprintf( '[add_to_cart id="%d"]', $product_id );
   echo do_shortcode( $shortcode );
}
```

Comment: That is what I needed and what I tried, but nothing shows up.
Only if i hard code the id

Comment: So then you are not correctly setting/retrieving the ID from your cookie? I would suggest that you edit your question with what you are using.